# What kind of view is the "New Contact" form on iOS?

Tags: ios

The "New Contact" form is a form that accets contact information on iOS. It has information such as name, phone number, birthday, photo, etc.

I am wondering what types of views were used to created this. For instance, a scroll view could be used or a table view. Why one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

A UITableView is a UIScrollView.

To name just one example, you may want to use a table view for the 'insert / delete' row / section functionality.

I would definitely use a UITableView for building forms.

Comment: Is the advantage of doing this so that you can easily insert / delete rows? If so, what is the best way to represent a row in the form so that it can be easily inserted?